# How do I pass and modify an optional argument to a function through a header file in C++?

Tags: c++, function, option-type

I am trying to create a function with an optional argument, where the optional argument gets modified/initialized in the function. This is part of a much larger program so I am using a header file. I am getting a compiler error and not sure how to fix it. Here is my code

## **Main**

```
#include "header.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <array>
#include <numbers>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int nr,np,nsize;
    nr = 3;
    nsize = nr++;
    vector<double> b(nsize);
    vector<double> x(nsize);
    vector<vector<double>> A(nsize, vector<double>(nsize));
    func(nr,b,x,A,np);
    cout<< np <<endl;
}
```

## **Header**

```
//same include statements, omitting for clarity
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H
     void func(int n,vector<double>& b,vector<double>& x,vector<vector<double>>& A,int np = -1);
#endif
```

## **func**

```
#include "header.h"

void func(int n,vector<double> &b,vector<double> &x,
vector<vector<double>> &A,int &np){

    np =2;

}
```

I can get it to compile without the ampersand before `np` in `func`, but then the return value of `np` does not change in `main`. I also tried having the ampersand on `np` in the header file but that also gives me an error. Any advice would be appreciated.

## **Errors**

Error with ampersand included in `header.h`:
header.h:24:97: error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'int&' to an rvalue of type 'int'
24 | void gausspivot(int n,vector& b,vector& x,vector<vector>& A,int &np = -1)

Error with ampersand in `func`:
undefined reference to `func(int, std::vector<double, std::allocator >&, std::vector<double, std::allocator >&, std::vector<std::vector<double, std::allocator >, std::allocator<std::vector<double, std::allocator > > >&, int)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: You modify the value, which means it has to be an lvalue. What do you expect to get modified if the default is used? I can't modify the *idea* of the number -1.

Comment: The default is just a number. In order to use a reference, you need to provide a variable that can be referred to.

Comment: Are you familiar with both pointers and references? Especially regarding which one supports the idea of not pointing/referring to a thing? (aka being optional) If not, then this is a good time to dive into that part of your learning C++.

Comment: Foregoing the putrid code smell of what I'm about to describe... make the argument a required reference., Then create an overload that does *not*  receive that argument at all, but rather prepares a local variable with the 'default' value, and then invokes the first function. Only attempt in well-ventilated rooms.

Comment: You may be able to do something by overloading the function - one accepts the argument by reference, and the other doesn't accept (and therefore doesn't modify) that argument - and might retrieve a default value if needed.

Comment: You might also consider [named parameters](https://pdimov.github.io/blog/2020/09/07/named-parameters-in-c20/)

Answer (score 2):

You achieve that by function overloading, i.e. having the same function with different parameters. The function with less parameters calls the function with more parameters and provides the default value.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void func(int n, std::vector<double>& b, std::vector<double>& x,
    std::vector<std::vector<double>>& A, int& np) {
    np = 2;
}

void func(int n, std::vector<double>& b, std::vector<double>& x,
    std::vector<std::vector<double>>& A) {
    std::cout << "You called the function with default value of -1\n";
    int dummy = -1;
    func(n, b, x, A, dummy);
    std::cout << "The value is now " << dummy <<"\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> b;
    std::vector< std::vector<double>> A;
    func(0, b, b, A);
}
```

Comment: I thought about function overloading for a hot second, but I will have various other functions that will also use that optional argument that it would just make the code too large and unruly. That is why I was trying to figure out a more elegant approach.

Answer (score 0):

One way to get this to compile is to have a global variable that serves as the default argument

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H

extern int np_default;

void func(int n, vector<double>& b,
     vector<double>& x, vector<vector<double>>& A,
     int& np = np_default);

#endif
```

Now this is ugly. Is the ugliness worth it? Only you can judge that.

Comment: I don't mind ugly, it is practical and it works. Thanks! But why does that work but specifying the integer as I had doesn't?

Comment: In terms of being ugly, while it can work, it is not thread-safe and the default will be changing as the function modifies it. Potential source of future maintenance headaches.

Comment: @JXS832 It's one of those things that seems obvious to me but I'm struggling to explain it. I would say that a non-const reference can only be bound to something that is modifiable, and an integer literal  like `-1` doesn't qualify as that. But that might be a slightly garbled explanation.

Comment: @john Got it, thanks. Could I do the same if np was a vector instead? do `extern vector<int> np_default`? and `void func(int n, vector<double>& b,
     vector<double>& x, vector<vector<double>>& A,
    vector<int>& np = np_default);`?

Comment: @JXS832 Yes that would also work.

Comment: @john Yeah, that's a nice ugly way of doing it ;-)

Comment: @JXS832 while that would work, why would you allow one to define multiple default values? This is plain confusing. Please, don't do that. Or at least tell me the company you work for, so I will never apply there.

Answer (score 0):

In the OP the function declaration in the .h file did not match the definition in the .cpp file. They must match in number and type of parameters. (Though neither version accomplishes your goal.)

I think that Thomas Weller's approach is well worth considering. You have indicated that it is not, however, practical for your needs.

I can suggest 2 alternatives that might better suit you. They both require some extra care in managing the no parameter provided case.

**Alternative 1** std::optional (requires C++17)

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>
#include <functional>

void func(int n, std::vector<double>& b, std::vector<double>& x,
    std::vector<std::vector<double>>& A, 
    std::optional<std::reference_wrapper< int> > np = 
        std::optional< std::reference_wrapper<int> >() ) 
{
  bool parameterProvided = np.has_value();
  int dummyIfNoParam = -1;

  int &localNpRef = np.has_value() ? *np : std::reference_wrapper<int>(dummyIfNoParam);

  if ( !parameterProvided  )
     std::cout <<"No parameter provided\n";
  
  std::cout << "Starting value " << localNpRef  <<'\n';
  localNpRef  = 42;
  std::cout << "Changed referred value " << localNpRef  <<'\n';
}
```

**Alternative 2** pass by pointer (requires taking the address of the argument at call site)

```
void func(int n, std::vector<double>& b, std::vector<double>& x,
        std::vector<std::vector<double>>& A, 
        int * pnp = nullptr )
{
  bool parameterProvided = (pnp != nullptr);
  int dummyIfNoParam = -1;
  int &localNpRef = pnp ? *pnp : dummyIfNoParam;


  std::cout << "Starting value " << localNpRef  <<'\n';
  localNpRef  = 42;
  std::cout << "Changed referred value " << localNpRef  <<'\n';
}
```

With the optional parameter provided, this would be called like:

```
int main()
{
  int np;
  std::vector<double> vect;
  std::vector< std::vector<double>> vectOfvect;

  func( 0, vect, vect, vectOfvect, &np );
}
```